# About a problem of fitting a cube in a subset of a sphere

Tags: convex-geometry, spherical-geometry

I am asking this question to know more about this problem that I find very interesting.

The problem is that suppose you have the unit 2-sphere $S^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and a measurable subset $A \subset S^2$ such that $\mu(A)=0.9\mu(S^2)$. Then prove that you can find a cube whose vertices will fit inside the set $A$.

This question has been asked and answered before:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573926/surface-of-a-sphere-and-cube

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499854/problem-regarding-the-fitting-cube-into-sphere

I want to know where this question originates from. Is this question part of some general type of questions that are encountered in a more general setting (for example coding theory)? What are the known developments?

Comment: "a cube that can fit inside the set $A$." More clearly, a cube all of whose vertices are in $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked a more general version of this question in an earlier question, 
[Regions on a sphere that avoid a fixed point set](https://mathoverflow.net/q/208230/6094).

---

[image]

          

<sup>A $5$-point set, its convex hull (blue) and smallest enclosing circle (red).</sup>

---

The OP's version is an $8$-point set. 
An upperbound was proved:
"for an $n$-point set $P$,
the area of an avoiding set cannot be larger
than $\frac{n-1}{n} A$, where $A$ is the area of the sphere."
For $n=8$, this gives an upper bound of $\frac{7}{8}=0.875$ which is smaller
than the OP's $0.9$.

To address the OP's specific questions:

> I want to know where this question originates from.

My version was original, but ...

> Is this question part of some general type of questions that are encountered in a more general setting?

Yes, *avoiding sets*. For example, there is quite a bit of literature on *mutually avoiding sets*, going back to Erdős. There is also considerable literature on sets avoiding integral (or rational) distances. See, e.g.,
the question [Integer-distance sets](https://mathoverflow.net/q/136925/6094). Or:
Kurz, Sascha, and Valery Mishkin. "[Open sets avoiding integral distances](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.0403)." *Discrete & Computational Geometry* 50.1 (2013): 99-123.